# Xamarin: Internal Error in the activation system when "Build All"

Tags: xamarin

I'm getting an Unhandled Exception Error when "Build All" in Xamarin starts as below:

```
Xamarin.Components.Ide.ApiClients.XamarinStoreException: No user found.
  at Xamarin.Components.Ide.ApiClients.XamarinStore.<StartTrial>m__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 t) [0x00049] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2508/0b60eecd/source/md-addins/Xamarin.Ide/Xamarin.Components.Ide/ApiClients/XamarinStore.cs:80 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[TAntecedentResult,TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00027] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:207 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00016] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2523
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please format your question.

Comment: It sounds like it is failing authentication.  Be sure you have logged into your Xamarin account in the IDE.

Comment: Jason! Thanks for the response. But I have logged into my Xamarin account already. Also I get the same error when I tried "Start Trial"